# How would I select all embedded documents of the same type in mgo Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a go application which uses mgo/mongodb. I'm using embedded documents rather than relational ones.

So I have... (some code redacted for brevity).

```
type User struct {
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
    Name        string        `form:"name" bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Password    string        `form:"password" bson:"password,omitempty" json:"password" binding:"required"`
    Email       string        `form:"email" bson:"email,omitempty" json:"email" binding:"required"`
    Artists     []Artist      `form:"artists" bson:"artists,omitempty" json:"artists" inline`
    Releases    []Release     `form:"releases" bson:"releases,omitempty" json:"releases" inline`
    ContentFeed []Content     `form:"content_feed" bson:"content_feed,omitempty" json:"content_feed" inline`
    Profile     Profile       `form:"profile" bson:"profile,omitempty" json:"profile" inline`
    TopTracks   []Track       `form:"top_tracks" bson:"top_tracks" json:"top_tracks" inline`
}

type Artist struct {
    Id     bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
    Title  string        `form:"title" bson:"title" json:"title"`
    Genres string        `form:"genres" bson:"genres" json:"genres"`
}

func (repo *ArtistRepo) GetArtists() ([]Artist, error) {
    results := &[]Artist{}
    err := repo.collection.Find(???).All(results)
    return results, err
}
```

I'm trying to get all of the artists, from all of the users essentially. But I can't figure what I need in my query? I've touched briefly on Map/Reduce, but it didn't seem to apply to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are assuming `mgo` is an "[ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)". But it's just a simple way to store data in Mongo. There are 3 different ways to fix your problem:

1. Put different types into different collections. That way, every document is the same type.  (Collections are like "tables" in a relational database).
2. Tag each thing with it's type (i.e. store the object type in a field), then you can query on it.
3. If you are feeling dangerous, you can assume all Artists have Genres, and all Users have a Profile. Then use `$exists` to select only that type.

The first option is the usual way to do it. You should have specific reasons for doing #2 or #3, as they could be slower.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

So for example, split our user and artist into two separate collection? But then how would I link a users artists to the user?

Comment: You can store an array of Object IDs, and simly remember to query the other collection. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-publisher-and-books

Comment: Is there a recommended way to do this using the Go mgo library? Or is it just a case of manually creating a new document, getting the ID, then updating the parent document and pushing the id into the array? 

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The latter. There are ORMs that handle parent/child relationships. But using an ORM is a complexity trade-off.